# Erro: argumento não-numérico para operador binário

Tags: r, funções

Estou trabalhando no seguinte código:

```
temperatura<-function(t){6/pi*atan(40*t-740)+7}#temperatura em função do tempo

Ratkowski<-function(t){0.04291^2*(temperatura(t)-3.57877)^2*(1-exp(1.13744*(temperatura(t)-41.64632)))^2}#modelo dinâmico

fq<-function(t){0.1*exp(Ratkowski(t))}

funcao<-function(t){integrate(fq,0,t)}
```

Estou tentando construir uma nova função definida como

```
funcao02<-function(t){funcao(t)/(funcao(t)+1)}
```

Está sendo gerado o seguinte erro:

> Error in funcao + 1 : argumento não-numérico para operador binário

Acredito que o valor de `funcao (resultado da integral)` não está sendo considerado como numérico. É isso mesmo? Como resolver o problema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note que o resultado de `funcao` não é numérico:

```
funcao(10)
1.000333 with absolute error < 1.1e-14
```

É necessário extrair o valor numérico (`1.000333`) deste resultado. Uma maneira de fazer isto é descobrir onde o `R`, dentro de `funcao(10)`, armazena este valor numérico. Faça isto através do comando `names`:

```
names(funcao(10))
[1] "value"        "abs.error"    "subdivisions" "message"      "call"
```

Para extrair **apenas** o valor numérico gerado por `funcao`, rode

```
funcao(10)$value
[1] 1.000333
```

Assim, basta corrigir a `funcao02` para refletir esta mudança:

```
funcao02 <- function(t){funcao(t)$value/(funcao(t)$value+1)}
funcao02(10)
[1] 0.5000831
```